# Troubleshooting slow writeback on bcache

Tags: software-raid, bcache

can somebody give me a hint, how to troubleshoot bcache in writeback mode?
I'm using a RAID 1 (2x500GB SSD) as caching device for the RAID 1 backing device (2x16TB HDD).
Dirty data of bcache is not going over ~730M, although I configured writeback_percent to 30. (30% of 500GB is definitely more than 730M ;-) ).

If I transfer a lot of GB its getting really slow and disk usage of HDD is only around 15%.

As this topic is new to me, i don't know where to start looking.
A little help would be great!

Thanks,
Angelo